# What object should be referenced to use the UsedRange property?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the UsedRange property.

I get

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

I have checked here and Googled it. I have followed syntax examples.

I deleted the temp files that caused an issue with it back in 2014.

The below code I also tried with totalRange = UsedRange.

```vb
Dim totalRange As Range
totalRange = VBA.UsedRange
Set totalRange = totalRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(totalRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                               totalRange.Columns.Count)
```

What it needs to do is select the total range of data, minus the header.

Comment: And if you need the whole code, just let me know!

Comment: The `VBA`-object has no member `UsedRange` - which is logical as `VBA` is related to the programming language, not the Excel object model.  If you want to use `UsedRange', you have to specify from which worksheet.

Comment: When you type `VBA.U` into the editor, Intellisense should pop up and provide you with all the available methods and properties of the `VBA` object beginning with the letter `U`. `UsedRange` will not be among those listed.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it not autofilling and knew I was led astray at some point, but had no idea what I was doing wrong.  I have yet to wrap my head around how the range object works fully, been tinkering with it for a short while now.  Maybe one day I'll grow up and take an actual class! Thank you, everyone, for your kind help. That is working now!

Answer (score 3):

Since `totalRange` is of type `Range` it is an object and objects have to use `Set` and `.UsedRange` must refer to a worksheet in a specific workbook.

```
Set totalRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
```

Comment: This is what I utilized to fix the problem, thank you so much!